# Issue running two timer related function on same object in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a food class, who's objects either get picked up for delivery or decay and are trashed. I have used the threading module to start two timers to see which of the two happens first and based on that the code proceeds.

The class definition is as below :

```
import threading
import random

class food():
  def __init__(self, name) :
    self._name = name
    self.isInKitchen = True

  def notifyDelivery(self):
    print ("order has been picked for delivery")
    self.isInKitchen = False

  def notifyDecay(self):
    print ("object has decayed")
    self.isInKitchen = False
```

I then create an object from this class and for the purpose of this question create two variables dictating the delivery pickup time and the expected decay time, as below

```
order = food("pasta")
decayPeriod = random.randint(5,10)
pickupPeriod = random.randint(2,10)
```

I then write the threads for tracking delivery and decay as below :

```
def deliver(order):
  if order.isInKitchen == False :
    order.notifyDelivery()

deliveryTimer = threading.Timer(pickupPeriod, deliver, [order])
deliveryTimer.start()


def decay(order):
  if order.isInKitchen == False :
    order.notifyDecay()

decayTimer = threading.Timer(decayPeriod, decay, [order])
decayTimer.start()
```

So my expectation is that whichever function triggers first should set the *order.isInKitchen* variable as *False* and then the other function will not be triggered. While I do get the output i hope for, the second thread keeps running till the *decayPeriod* or *pickupPeriod* is reached. At that point it checks that the *isInKitchen* property of the object is *False* and does nothing before terminating the thread.

I am trying to find out if there is a way to stop the second thread as soon as the function in the first thread is triggered. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can call `.cancel()` on the other thread?

Comment: Where would that cancel function be called?

Comment: `deliver` could call `decayTimer.cancel()` and vis-versa

Comment: That worked! thank you so much @IainShelvington